# Python Launcher automatically opens

Tags: python

I am using a MacBook Pro, every time I use `command`+`F5` in IDLE to run my python scripts, Python Launcher would automatically opens. However, the logo keeps jumping on my Dock and I actually got the message "Application Not Responding". I later found that if I run my script from Terminal, Python Launcher will also automatically opens and quits after several seconds.
Is this normal. If not, how could I solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: What do your python scripts *do*?

Comment: My script reads in several CSV files, does some calculations, and then write the results in a new CSV file. It seems that Python Launcher opens when writing the file.